Candles high lower than next candles close
Learning Pine Script, I wonder why this simple code doesn't do the job. I wan't to mark every candle with a lower high than next candles close. Here is my code:
condition = high < close[1]

plotshape(condition, title="High < Next Close", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)

The result ist something like this. Can anyone help to fix this?


You got your indexing wrong. Your script will be executed on each bar. So, on the current bar, you want to reference high of the previous bar.
condition = high[1] < close

If you want to mark the candle with the lower high (previous candle), then you need to add offset=-1 to your plotshape().

Perfect, thank you!

Your current condition is not marking the high of the current candle to the low or the close of the next candle.Try this code instead:
indicator("Mark Lower High Than Next Close", overlay=true)
condition = high < close[1]
plotshape(series=condition, title="High < Next Close", style=shape.arrowup, 
location=location.abovebar, color=color.red)


This is pretty much the same code and will generate identical results.

The function ta.valuewhen(close1, close, 1) gets the close price of the next candle by shifting the close series one bar forward. The result of the condition is then stored in the 'lowerHighCondition' and used to plot the arrow on the candle.
//@version=5
indicator("Mark Lower Highs", overlay=true)
    
// Define the condition
lowerHighCondition = high < ta.valuewhen(close[1], close, 1)
    
// Plot markers on the chart where the condition is true
plotshape(series=lowerHighCondition, location=location.belowbar,
color=color.red, style=shape.labeldown, text="Lower High")

Example on the chart
